# Proof: $|||AB|||^ \frac{1}{2} \leq |||A ^ \frac{1}{2}B ^ \frac{1}{2}||| $?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

I am looking for a proof of the following:
\begin{equation*}
|||AB|||^ \frac{1}{2} \leq |||A ^ \frac{1}{2}B ^ \frac{1}{2}||| 
\end{equation*}
Where A, B are positive, hermitian matrices, and $|||⋅|||$ is a unitarily invariant norm.

Perhaps someone has a reference to a book, or paper that contains such a proof? I have search myself and cannot seem to find anything. Also tried writing matlab code to find counterexamples and prove the contrary but that does not return anything - which leads to me to believe a proof must exist. Thank you.

Comment: Richard Bellman dealt with such a stuff. So books “Introduction to matrix analysis” (Ch. 8) by Richard Bellman and “Inequalities” by Edwin F. Beckenbach and Richard Bellman may  be useful for you. Though I did not find a similar inequality it these books, maybe you will find in them some useful inequalities of references.

Comment: Are you assuming that the norm is submultiplicative? Otherwise, it is easy to find a counterexample.

Comment: yes, as a unitarily invariant matrix norm on square matrices i am assuming that it is submultiplicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality does not always hold. Put $X=A^{1/2}$ and $Y=B^{1/2}$. The inequality is equivalent to $|||X^2Y^2|||\le|||XY|||^2$ for every pair of positive definite matrices $X,Y$ and for every unitarily invariant matrix norm $|||\cdot|||$. Now, take $X=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&1},\ Y=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$ and the operator norm (induced 2-norm), we have
$$
|||X^2Y^2|||\approx23.6>21.8\approx|||XY|||^2.
$$

Comment: I think you used the spectral norm (largest singular value) i.e  you used norm(X*Y,2) in matlab, which according to my understanding is not unitarily invariant. You meant to use the Frobenius norm. i.e norm(X*Y, 'fro'). This however still leads to a similar result:
$$
|||X^2Y^2|||\approx23.6>22\approx|||XY|||^2.
$$
I still have some questions; how did you find this example? could you perhaps share a matlab code you used? and why did you chose to reformulate the inequality, what does that change?

Comment: @Dani The *spectral norm* is just another name for the *operator norm/induced 2-norm*. I often avoid using the name "spectral norm" when the matrix concerned is not necessarily Hermitian. The spectral norm **is** unitarily invariant. So is the Frobenius norm. I found the example by hand. Obviously the inequality holds if $X$ is a scalar matrix. So, to construct a counterexample, I tried the next simplest positive diagonal matrix: X=diag(2,1). The inequality also holds if X and Y commute. So, I modified X by a little to obtain some Y that doesn't commute with X.

Comment: understood. thank you!